# Rails Nokogiri get xml from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I recently learned how to import XML feeds into rails using nokogiri with the following code.

Instead of downloading my feed from an URL, I have the option to access it directly from an URL.

let's say that URL is `www.feedurl.com'

how would I update the below code to get it from that URL:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord 
    def self.xml_parser
        doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("#{Rails.root}/datafeed.xml"))
        frothieproducts = doc.xpath('//FeedItems/FeedItem')
        frothieproducts.map do |feeditem|
            product = Product.new
            product.product_name = feeditem.xpath('Name').text
            product.product_description = feeditem.xpath('Description').text
            product.product_link = feeditem.xpath('Url').text
            product.save!
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Your question isn't complete. We need code that's runnable and demonstrates the problem. Add the minimum HTML necessary to duplicate the problem into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the xml data from `www.feedurl.com` you can change this line:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("#{Rails.root}/datafeed.xml"))
```

to

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.feedurl.com"))
```

Comment: A better question is, if the Rails code is generating the XML, why is Nokogiri being used to change the rendered XML? Change the XML upstream, in the source.

Answer (score 0):

doc = Nokogiri::XML(URI.open("http://www.feedurl.com"))